# How to handle NaN in Bosun?

Tags: bosun

I have 2 metrics and try to find the difference of average value between them in percentage like `100*(m1+m2)/m1` but this obviously produces `NaN` if `m1` turns to zero.

How should I handle this case if I don't want to alert when the metrics turn to zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bools bosun has a [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) like behavior. Since Bosun's expression language lacks if statements, you need to use a bool operation to see if the divisor is 0 first:

```
$foo = 0
$foo && 1/$foo
```

Since $foo is zero, the statement is "not true" so 1/$foo is not factored into the final calculation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works for me.
I've never thought of using expression editor in that sense. It should really help to try playing with expression in it before actually trying them as rules.

Comment: @timurb: yea Craig added that about a month ago, nice to do variables earlier in the workflow

Comment: If you use this approach then you lose the 1/$foo value when $foo is not 0:

$foo = 5
$foo && 1/$foo

result: 1 (i.e. true)

what if you want to have 1/$foo if $foo != 0 but 0 if $foo == 0?